# AMP-Linker - The script tag contains invalid JSON that cannot be parsed

Tags: amp-analytics

I received the following notification in GSC

> The script tag contains invalid JSON that cannot be parsed."

It came up a couple of days after we enabled the linker feature.

This is the amp-analytics code:

```
<body>
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{
"vars": {
"account": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
},
"triggers": {
"trackPageview": {
"on": "visible",
"request": "pageview"
}
}
"linkers": {
      "enabled": true
    }
}
</script>
```

Any advice on what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The most universal approach to solving any "invalid JSON" issue is using [JSON Validator](https://hinty.io/devforth/fix-the-script-tag-contains-invalid-json-that-cannot-be-parsed/)

Answer (score 3):

Missing comma after `triggers: {...},`